# What Does this code mean in BEP20 token writting with Solidity

Tags: blockchain, solidity, bep20

I'm trying to understand what this lines of BEP20 code mean, it is written in solidity

```
constructor () {
    _rOwned[owner()] = _rTotal;
    IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E);
    uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory())
        .createPair(address(this), _uniswapV2Router.WETH());
    uniswapV2Router = _uniswapV2Router;
    _isExcludedFromFee[owner()] = true;
    _isExcludedFromFee[address(this)] = true;
    emit Transfer(address(0), owner(), _tTotal);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first lines, he instanciate UniswapV2Router pointing the address router to PancakeSwap. This because, he want to create a liquidity pool with his TOKEN and BNB, indeed after this instanciating  operation he call `createPair()` that allows him to create this pair between his smart contract and the address WETH().

**IMPORTANT:** WETH() is a function that provider the chain native wrapped coin address where smart contract was deployed. For example: If I create a pair instanciating Uniswap router on Ethereum blockchain then WETH() will return address about `WETH` (Wrapping Ether) address present into Etheruem. On the contrary if I instanciate Uniswap Router with its address present into binance smart chain (and so I refers to Pancakeswap in this case), the value of WETH() will be `WBNB` address.

After this lines of code, I assume that he excluded from paying a fee for only transactions the `owner()` address (who deployed the smart contract for the first time) and smart contract itself.

Finally he emitted a Transfer event passing : `address(0)` (0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000), `owner()` and `total supply`.

More information about pair on [documentation](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/concepts/V3-overview/glossary#pair).

Comment: Thanks for the info! About the address in line 3 "0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E" What action will actually happen on the address!

Comment: Initializes a pointer to the 0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E address and in this way his smart contract (if implements IUniswapRouterV2 interface) through _uniswapV2Router variable can use its methods and variables (if public).